How to auto assign a number to a row based on conditional formatting
I have a contact form where I want to assign a priority contact based on how many days it has been since the last contact.

In the example image I have the the conditional formatting in Column E which is Excel's standard colour scale system.
What I would like is for the cells in Column A to be auto filled with numbers based on the colours of the scale, so anything formatted in red would be a higher priority than anything in Green.
I am not versed in VBA but am willing to use it if someone can provide guidance.
Is this even possible?

Your priority is already shown based on the color, no? And the color is based on the values so you could just as well set up a formula indicating what takes priority based on said values. Conditional formatting is supposed to give you an easy visual not be the base for some formula.

Yes but Ideall I would also like it to auto sort where possible, so as the conditional formatting updates as does the priority cell and reorders the rows as when a contact is considered 'finished' I'll remove the conditional formatting and hide the data

Is coloring a ranked result or an absolute ? If ranked what would be with identical data?

@Blackcat Unsure how to define this as this is the one of the default Conditional formatting setting that Excel provides.

In Excel, you cannot base a number on a colour, but you can base a colour on a value. So, using the colour as an input is not a good idea.
However, the following formula might be interesting for you:
=MATCH(E2;SORT(E$2:E$5);0)

As you can see, you take the days since last contact, order that list, and take the index of every value out of this sorted series, resulting in a kind of priority. Is this what you want?
Hereby a screenshot of the results:


This could work. I'll try it and let you know how it goes!

I have tried to get this to work however I believe that the version of Excel we have doesn't support Match formulae

According to this URL ("https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a"), the Match() function applies to quite some Excel versions. Are you sure it's not translated into some local language?
